# Determining the that the different sets of the type [c] for c ∈ C result partition of C.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, set-partition

I'm trying to solve the following problem, Let A and B be sets with injections f:A→B and g:B→A.  Fix a∈A and define [a] ={x∈A | ∃n∈ℕ s.t.  (g◦f)<sup>n</sup>(a) =x or (g◦f)<sup>n</sup>(x) =a}.

I'd want to show that the various sets of the form [a] for a ∈ A give a partition of A. I'd also want to offer an example of how [a] may be a finite set even though A and B are infinite.

I thought that if I show that A ≠ B, so A∩B = ∅ and showing that  there wouldn't be any empty subsets because the function is not necessarily surjective, so we have to exclude empty set, would help me to demonstrate that the different sets of  [a] for a ∈ A result in an A partition; however, I don't think I can show this with only this information. Could someone help me on how to proceed for solving this question? All help is appreciated.

Note: Btw, by having a exponent in the composite function indicates that for example for the (g◦f)<sup>n</sup>(a) =x, it means that  (g◦f)<sup>2</sup> (a) =(g◦f◦g◦f)(a) = x and (g◦f)<sup>3</sup>(a) =(g◦f◦g◦f◦g◦f)(a) = x

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for the links

Comment: Have you worked through an example, like, say, $A = B = \Bbb Z$, $f(x) = 2x$, $g(x) = x-2$?

Comment: @JohnHughes I tried with a very similar example but I couldn't demonstrate that the different sets of [a] for a ∈ A result in an A partition, additionaly, I think  the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, which states that if there exist injective functions f : A → B and g : B → A between the sets A and B, then there exists a bijective function h : A → B plays a role in the solution but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JohnHughes Now, I tried to do it through the example you gave, but I could not reach a successful result. Could you give me a little more insight about how your suggestion will help me to proceed the question?

Comment: My suggestion was that if you understand one or two examples really well, you often find the insight needed to handle the general question. I was once told that Euler would usually work out about 50 examples before trying to prove something. I assume that's apocryphal, but it's still worth thinking about. Why did I choose those particular functions? Because $f$, through injective, is not surjective, and $g$ has the property that $g(f(2)) = 2$, and I thought that might lead to something interesting. I certainly have not thought through a full solution.